# Отладка native кода в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

На днях Google пообещали возможной работу с native кодом в Android Studio. Для этого нужно установить через SDK manager пакет ndk-bundle и обновить Android Studio до самой последней версии (Canary ветка). А как настроить? Вот ссылка на источник. [Developer Tools](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-m-developer-preview-tools.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UP. Выложили. Описание на странице  [Android NDK Preview](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview)

> Они ещё не выложили, только пообещали. В первых нескольких релизах не будет. Ждем...
>
> "As announced at Google I/O, Android Studio 1.3 will include C/C++ support as well, but that is not included in the first couple of preview builds."
> http://tools.android.com/recent

Answer (score 4):

Работа с нативным кодом была еще раньше в Android Studio, просто не столь удобна как ее сделали "на днях" (кусок Clion запихнули в Android Studio). Для работы вам потребуется:

1. Скачать [пакет](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html) android ndk;
2. В самой студии в файле local.properties указать путь к ndk;
3. Для настройки обновления (Canary ветка) нужно перейти в Settings->Updates поставить голочку на Automatically check updates for и выбираем Canary Chanell;
4. Создать папку jni в директории main, там будут храниться файлы нативного кода. Подробнее смотрите [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/203014/) на хабре;

Comment: По второму пункту - это же самое можно сделать в окне Project Structure, чтобы не лазить по конфигам.

Comment: Я сделал всё, что написал AdamLuisSean, но у меня не появилась возможность поставить Breakpoint в *.c файле в функции.
Статья же от 2013-го года. Ребята, это всё не то. Я спрашиваю конкретно о нововведении, которое показали на Google I/O 2015.